# How to hide form fields in a new company

Tags: security, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I have an AX 2009 installation with 5 companies.

The current security configuration contains groups of users which are company specific, and the companies are in their own domains (1 per company).

**I am adding a new company, however for this new company I do not want various groups to be visible on certain forms.**

**How do I achieve this without affecting the existing companies?**

I have tried (in test environment) to add a new security key, however the security key defaults to "no access". When applied to a group on a form, the group becomes hidden; This is okay for my new company, but I would then need to go through every other user group and set back to full control, so that users in the existing companies can still see the field group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in function in AX called `curExt()` that will tell you the name of the users current company. You could do the following on the form if you set the auto declare property of the groups on the form to Yes:

```
if(curExt() == "NewCompany")
{
     GroupNameThatShouldNotBeVisible.visible(false);
}
```

Then you will not need to worry about setting up security keys for all the companies.

Comment: I agree that using curExt() could be the best option to avoid using security keys/permission, since they can be rather cumbersome, as you've found.

Comment: Thanks Michael + Vince. I forgot to mention this may be user group specific in the question, but that is only my own fault.

Comment: The more I think about it, it really should be possible to handle this in security, it is something MS really should look at in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Michael Brown and Vince Perta just on the basis of best practices and best practices here would be to use security keys and domain setup.  That said however, if you're not a consultant working across many clients and you're an in-house developer...it's not a big deal to use curExt() and hardcode the companies and security settings you want.

I'm having a bit of trouble following exactly how you're doing the security groups and why it's difficult...but I'd make a copy of Live to Test, make the security changes as needed for all of the companies, then just export them out to a file, then import into Live.  Are you worried about the disruption to the live users or what exactly?

Comment: Yes, there is a worry of disruption to live users. I also have to take into consideration the role of the consultant who administers our live security, and try to make their job easier.

Comment: If you're worried about the disruption, just export the security keys and import...it would also make for a better "cut over" procedure.  If you're audited for SOX purposes, this would be a better change too.

Comment: I did not state that my answer was a best practice. I agree that this would be better handled through security, but in the question Anthony stated that he had tried this in Test and did not want to make the changes to all security groups throughout the system. My solution provides a way to do this. Since this is a Q&A site for programming, I gave the possible X++ answer to the question rather than the security answer which Anthony already knew.

Comment: Thanks Michael. @AlexK I dont have any control over the business process around security. All I want to do is make life easier for everyone (including myself) when releasing developments.

Comment: @Michael Brown, I didn't mean anything negative by my comment.  I prefer your way personally, I just wanted the "best practices" comment in the thread in case somebody google'd this.  I tried to note that either way was fine.

Comment: @AlexK I understand, I was just clarifying my position. Sometimes this is difficult in text only formats.